# The probability that non-negative difference of the digits at equal distances from both the ends is always one is

Tags: probability

$9-$digit number formed using only the digits $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ without repetition,then the probability that non-negative difference of the digits at equal distances from both the ends is always one is
$(A)\frac{1}{48}\hspace{1cm}(B)\frac{1}{96}\hspace{1cm}(C)\frac{1}{192}\hspace{1cm}(D)\frac{1}{384}$

---

Let 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 be the nine positions.The digits whose non negative difference is required $1$ should be put at positions first and ninth,second and eighth,third and seventh,fourth and sixth.
And 1,2 and 2,1 and 2,3 and 3,2 and 3,4 and 4,3 and so on are the numbers whose non negative difference is $1$.We have $16$ such pairs.
So i found the required probability as $\frac{4\times 16\times 7!}{9!}=\frac{8}{9}$.
But my answer is not matching any of the choices.What wrong have i done?What is the correct way to solve this question?Please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The numerator is not correct. Note that the 9-digit numbers cannot use digits more than once.

Hints:

- The number in the center (the 5th position) must be odd. (Why?)
- After choosing the number in the center, the four [unordered] pairs of digits are fixed. For example, if $1$ is in the center, then you must have $(2,3)$, $(4,5)$, $(6,7)$, and $(8,9)$ as your pairs. How many ways are there to place these pairs in the remaining $8$ positions?

  > There are $4!$ ways to place the four pairs in order, and then $2^4$ ways to flip the digits within each pair.

Comment: According to your solution,probability is $\frac{5\times 2^4\times 4!}{9!}=\frac{1}{189}$,but it is not in the options.Isn't it?@angryavian

Comment: Hello, I am also getting $1/189$ by brute force. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ganeshie8/Lqbagygh/embedded/result/) you may find the total numbers that satisfy the given requirement...

Comment: @pooja  I looked into and verified your enumeration. Looks OK to me.  If we want $\frac{1}{192}$ as the answer, then we must have only $1890$ enumerations. But you do have $1920$ distinct verifiable enumerations, and there is a fairly straightforward explanation given by **angryavian** too.